# Mongoose nested document validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    working_hours: {
        weekday: {
            start: String,
            end: String
        },
        weekend: {
            start: String,
            end: String
        }
    }
});
```

and I would like to validate the `start` and `end` fields for each of `weekday` and `weekend`.
I am currently doing so very explicitly using regex as below:

```
restaurantSchema.path('working_hours.weekday.start').validate(function(time) {
    var timeRegex = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
    return timeRegex.test(time);
}, 'Time must be in the format `hh:mm` and be a valid time of the day.');

restaurantSchema.path('working_hours.weekday.end').validate(function(time) {
    var timeRegex = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
    return timeRegex.test(time);
}, 'Time must be in the format `hh:mm` and be a valid time of the day.');

restaurantSchema.path('working_hours.weekend.start').validate(function(time) {
    var timeRegex = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
    return timeRegex.test(time);
}, 'Time must be in the format `hh:mm` and be a valid time of the day.');

restaurantSchema.path('working_hours.weekend.end').validate(function(time) {
    var timeRegex = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
    return timeRegex.test(time);
}, 'Time must be in the format `hh:mm` and be a valid time of the day.');
```

There's got to be a better way than this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of mongoose's custom validation, you could wrap a custom validate object which you can reuse. This should cut down on all that boilerplate. See the [Mongoose validation docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

```
const dateValidation = {
  validator: (value) => /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/.test(value),
  message: 'Time must be in the format hh:mm and be a valid time of the day.'
}

var restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    working_hours: {
        weekday: {
            start: {type: String, validate: dateValidation},
            end: {type: String, validate: dateValidation}
        },
        weekend: {
            start: {type: String, validate: dateValidation},
            end: {type: String, validate: dateValidation}
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a much better alternative, Thanks a lot!